# Subprocess Python Error

Tags: python, terminal, subprocess

when I run this subprocess command from python, it seems like python stalls and never outputs anything :

```
msg = subprocess.call(['/Users/admirmonteiro/bin/Praat', '/Users/admirmonteiro/tmp/tmp.praat'])
```

but when I run the command itself from the terminal, it runs and closes as it should :

```
Praat /tmp/tmp.praat
```

Is anyone able to tell me why python is not finishing up the code and is stalling and not outputting anything?

thanks !

Comment: Do you need to do something with the subprocess's stdin stdout and stderr? does the subprocess produce a lot of output, or expect input? Perhaps by inheriting from the parent process they're causing the subprocess to think there's data to be read and so it's waiting to be able to read stdin?

Comment: No I believe not(the input to the Praat is the tmp.praat), there is no output at all, it actually opens the praat tool itself and expects me to run the file and when i do there is an output from the subprocess command. I do not want this process though. I want it to be as if I was running it from the terminal, which when i call it, it runs Praat /tmp/tmp.praat and closes itself.

Comment: Does it work on the command line if you run something like "cat /dev/null | Praat /tmp/tmp.praat | cat"? Wondering if the Praat process is detecting a tty stdin/stdout and behaving differently because of that.

Comment: Hi, Tom, yes it does with no errors.

Comment: what do you see if you type `type Praat` in the terminal? What happens if you pass the same file `/tmp/tmp.praat` instead of `/User.../tmp.praat`?

Answer (score 0):

You could try making sure the stdin and stdout (or other file descriptors) are not causing the problem:

```
p = subprocess.POpen(
    ['/Users/admirmonteiro/bin/Praat', '/Users/admirmonteiro/tmp/tmp.praat'],
    stdin=subprocess.PIPE,
    stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
    stderr=subprocess.STDOUT,
    close_fds=True,
)
print p.communicate()
print p.wait()
```

Comment: I tried this but it opens up Praat again and expects me to press the run button and then quit it before python returns anything.

Answer (score -1):

it seems you have exchanged the arguments.

```
msg = subprocess.call(['/Users/admirmonteiro/bin/Praat', '/Users/admirmonteiro/tmp/tmp.praat'])
```

should be

```
msg = subprocess.call([ '/Users/admirmonteiro/tmp/tmp.praat','/Users/admirmonteiro/bin/Praat'])
```

Comment: ok, odd but when i run this : msg = subprocess.call([ '/Users/admirmonteiro/tmp/tmp.praat','/Users/admirmonteiro/bin/Praat'],shell=True) I get this error :/Users/admirmonteiro/bin/Praat: /Users/admirmonteiro/tmp/tmp.praat: Permission denied.

Comment: perfect. now change the permission of '/Users/admirmonteiro/tmp/tmp.praat to be executable 
    
   `chmod +x '/Users/admirmonteiro/tmp/tmp.praat`

 if you are on a *nix platform

Comment: Have a new error : Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Users/admirmonteiro/anaconda/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 522, in call
    return Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs).wait()
  File "/Users/admirmonteiro/anaconda/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 710, in __init__
    errread, errwrite)
  File "/Users/admirmonteiro/anaconda/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 1335, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception
OSError: [Errno 8] Exec format error

Comment: This answer looks wrong - the first param to call is meant to be the arg list of the process to be exec'd, and of those, the first element is the executable (sys.argv[0]). The order should be `["runnable_thing.py", "arg1", "arg2"]` as per the original post.